# scrollheight of an element gives undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an element I've given CSS `overflow: scroll;`. Now in jQuery I want to have it's original height (containing all child elements' height). Children under this element are dynamically changing. I want to have height on scroll event.
Here is the code:

```
$("#container").scroll(function(e) {
    scrollAll();
});

function scrollAll(){
    var elemHeight = $("#container").scrollHeight;
    var scrollHeight = $("#scrollbars").scrollHeight;
    var ratio = elemHeight / scrollHeight;

    $("#outup").html( elemHeight +" and "+ scrollHeight +" ratio "+ ratio +" = "+ ($("#container").scrollTop()));
}
```

Issue: It throws `scrollHeight is undefined` error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no `scrollHeight` in jQuery - it's `scrollTop()`:

```
var elemHeight = $("#container").scrollTop();
var scrollHeight = $("#scrollbars").scrollTop();
```

Alternatively if you want to use the native `scrollHeight` property, you need to access the DOM element in the jQuery object directly, like this:

```
var elemHeight = $("#container")[0].scrollHeight;
var scrollHeight = $("#scrollbars")[0].scrollHeight;
```

Or like this:

```
var elemHeight = $("#container").prop('scrollHeight');
var scrollHeight = $("#scrollbars").prop('scrollHeight');
```

Comment: I've gone through, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100099/checking-for-scrollheight-of-an-element-sometimes-returning-0

Comment: Great its working now, can you let me know what is the difference in $("#container")[0] and $("#container").

Comment: `$("#container")` returns the element wrapped in a jQuery object, `$("#container")[0]` returns the DOM element itself.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Jquery 1.6 or above, use prop to access the value.

```
$("#container").prop('scrollHeight')
```

Previous versions used to get the value from attr but not post 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div')['prevObject'][0]['scrollingElement'].scrollHeight;
```

Try to print `console.log($('#div')` which returns all properties related to that div or any HTML element