# jQuery auto scroll vertically in a div

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

Can anyone suggest a good simple jQuery vertical autoscroller script? one that's not bloat, I just need for it to auto start and scroll 6 or more `li`in a div. i tried the **jquery.autoscroll.js** but couldn't get it to auto start.

```
$.fn.autoscroll.defaults = { 
   start: { 
      step: 50, 
      scroll: true, 
      direction: "down", 
      pauseOnHover: true 
   }, 
   delay: 5000, 
   ffrw: { 
      speed: "fast", 
      step: 100 
   } 
};
```

Answer (score 17):

```
var div = $('div.autoscrolling');
var scroller = setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    div.scrollTop(++pos);
}, 100)​
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/52jzM/1/).

**EDIT:**

To stop scrolling when the div has scrolled to the bottom add the following check at the end of the above `function() {}` -

```
if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight)
   clearInterval(scroller);
}
```

Comment: and when hits the end, it will try to scroll and scroll and scroll and scroll

Comment: @FlashThunder: There are many answers already available on SO to check that. Check if `scrollTop` has reached the container height and use `clearInterval`. Big deal. How does that warrant a down vote? Suggest a solution and not just the problem.  Go do some searching first.

Answer (score 3):

simplyScroll is a cool plugin http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

Answer (score 1):

Robin's answer didn't quite do the trick for me, for several reasons, so here's a modified and extended version of his approach:

```
var div = $('.scrollbit');

$('.scrollbit').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(evt) {
    if (evt.type === 'DOMMouseScroll' || evt.type === 'keyup' || evt.type === 'mousewheel') {

    }
    if (evt.originalEvent.detail < 0 || (evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta && evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0)) { 
        clearInterval(scrollbit);
    }
    if (evt.originalEvent.detail > 0 || (evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta && evt.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0)) { 
        clearInterval(scrollbit);
    }
});

var scrollbit = setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    if ((div.scrollTop() + div.innerHeight()) >= div[0].scrollHeight) {
        clearInterval(scrollbit);
    }
    div.scrollTop(pos + 1);
}, 100);
```

with help from anonymous user1248475 here:

[Detect whether scroll event was created by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035896/detect-whether-scroll-event-was-created-by-user/)

and this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9392134

Hope that's helpful for anyone looking to solve the issue of how to auto scroll a div with jquery and stop when user scrolls manually.

Answer (score 1):

The autoscroll.js download at github has the wrong files in the download.
If you search there, you can find them.

I've made a working demo at the link below, which you can copy from if you like.

[autoscroll.js at github](https://github.com/wilkerlucio/jquery-autoscroll/tree/master/examples/images)

[my working autoscroll demo](http://nbson.com/autoscroll/)