# jQuery auto scroll - easy fix

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script which scrolls down the body of the page until it reaches the bottom.

```
        var div = $('body');
        setInterval(function(){
            var pos = div.scrollTop();
            div.scrollTop(++pos);
            }, 100).scrollTop(0);
```

This script works fine however I need to to almost instantly jump back up to the top of the page after completing this process and then repeat over and over. I have played around with it but not having much luck. If anyone has an easy fix that would be fantastic.

Gambit

Comment: Why do you have scrollTop(0) on your setInterval ? That is incorrect as setInterval return value does not contain a definition for scroll top.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
var div = $('div.autoscrolling');
setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    div.scrollTop(++pos);
}, 100)​
```

[jQuery auto scroll vertically in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164263/jquery-autoscroll)