# jQuery scrollTop() doesn't work and returns zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to convert JavaScript into jQuery but it doesn't seem to work (alert returns zero). In this thread "[scrollheight of an element gives undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392099/scrollheight-of-an-element-gives-undefined-value)" I've learned that I should use scrollTop() jQuery function but it doesn't return what I want.

**Edit:**

HTML code:

Istorija (paspauskite)

```
<div class="panel">
    <table>
        <tr style="border-top: none;">
            <td>Dėl tvarkos, visi sąrašai yra 30 įrašų ilgio, išskyrus sąskaitos papildymus bei lėšų išsiėmimus.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="panel-nested-parent active" style="max-height: 94px;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Pelnas nuo įsigytų (1 kaimynas)</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="border: none;">
                <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
                    <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
                    <div class="panel-nested">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="border: none;">
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Gyvulys</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Kiekis</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; border-right: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Pelnas</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Višta</td>
                                    <td>1 vnt.</td>
                                    <td>1 Eur</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
                    <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested">Fermų (10%)</button>
                    <div class="panel-nested">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Ferma</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Kiekis</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; border-right: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Pelnas</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Vištidė</td>
                                    <td>1 vnt.</td>
                                    <td>1 Eur</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
                    <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
                    <div class="panel-nested">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Fabrikas</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Kiekis</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; border-right: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Pelnas</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tešlos</td>
                                    <td>1 vnt.</td>
                                    <td>1 Eur</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
                    <button class="accordion-nested">Kepyklų (10%)</button>
                    <div class="panel-nested">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Kepykla</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Kiekis</th>
                                    <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; border-right: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Pelnas</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Blynų su mėsa</td>
                                    <td>1 vnt.</td>
                                    <td>1 Eur</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


var accHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-header");
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var accNestedParent = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-nested-parent");
var accNested = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-nested");
var panelNested = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-nested");
```

JS Works:

```
for (i = 0; i < accHeader.length; i++) {
    accHeader[i].onclick = function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
            $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");
        } else {
            $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
            $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");

            var accPanel = this.nextElementSibling;
            var nextAcc = this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;

            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).next().addClass('active');
            $(this).next().next().addClass("top-border");
            if (accPanel.style.maxHeight) {
                accPanel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                accPanel.style.maxHeight = accPanel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
            alert(accPanel.scrollHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery doesn't work:

```
for (i = 0; i < accNested.length; i++) {
    accNested[i].onclick = function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.panel').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
            $('.panel-nested').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel-nested').css('max-height', '');
            $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-nested').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");
        } else {
            $('.panel').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
            $('.panel-nested').removeClass('active');
            $('.panel-nested').css('max-height', '');
            $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion-nested').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");

            var accPanel = $('.panel');
            var nextAcc = this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;

            $('.panel-nested').addClass("active");
            $('.accordion-nested').addClass('active');
            $('.accordion-nested').addClass("top-border");
            if (accPanel.css('max-height')) {
                accPanel.css('max-height', '');
            } else {
                accPanel.css('max-height', accPanel.scrollTop() + "px");
            }
            alert(accPanel.scrollTop());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post whole code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is -I hope- the result you want to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>*INCLUDE YOUR JQUERY LIBRARY*</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #div{
            border: 1px solid black;
            width:900px;
            height: 900px;
            max-height: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">My div</div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var accPanel = $('#div');
        var maxHeigth = $('#div').css( "max-height" );
        var height = accPanel.height();
        if (maxHeigth == 'none') {
            console.log('No max-height set by default.')
            console.log('Changing to ', height)
            accPanel.css('max-height', accPanel.height() + "px");
        } else {
            console.log('Currently it has max-height equal to ', height)
            console.log('Changing to 0px');
            accPanel.css('max-height', '0px');
        }
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Try it in your browser as it is, I've added some log shown into the console that should help.

Let me know,
Laura

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the jQuery scrollTop() function improperly.
It is not a CSS propery that you can assign to an element.

Indeed, it is a function, so you cannot do :

```
accPanel.css('max-height', accPanel.scrollTop() + "px")
```

If you want to add as CSS property the max-height you should use [.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
accPanel.height();
```

Hope this could help,

Laura.

Comment: Okay ,lets solve it. You need to set css max-heigth equal to the accPanel.height() right?

Comment: Try with the new answer, hope this could help.