# Prepending Old Chat Messages to Chat Box

Tags: javascript, loops, scroll, chat, addeventlistener

I'm trying to prepend old messages to a chatbox when the user scrolls to the top. I'm using eventListeners as the code illustrates, but I'm running into an error where only the last chatbox is working properly. It seems that bodies[index].scrollTop and bodies[index].scrollHeight always returns 0 with the exception of bodies[lastIndex]. Why might this be? (logging bodies[index] correctly returns the div element)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.popup-messages').forEach((item, index) =>
{   
    item.addEventListener('scroll', async function()
    {
        if (chatReady[index] == true && bodies[index].scrollTop == 0)
        {
            chatReady[index] = false;
            var previousHeight = bodies[index].scrollHeight;
                    
            await getMessages(item.id.replace(":body", ""));
                    
            var heightDiff = bodies[index].scrollHeight - previousHeight;
            bodies[index].scrollTop += heightDiff;
        }
    })
})
```

Edit: If there's a different way to make multiple eventListeners dynamically, please share it with me as it would help a lot.

Comment: Are you calling this snippet at the proper time? Like are of the`.popup-messages`s loaded on page before you run this script?

Comment: Yes, .popup-messages are established before this code block occurs.

Comment: What does bodies[index].getBoundingClientRect() return?

Comment: a DOMRECT with all values being 0. even for the last index which works properly!

Comment: After a little bit of reflecting, why do you care about the heights of the elements? When you add them, does the page not set the height according to the contents of the text? Do you have an example of what you're trying to acomplish?

Comment: When you just prepend new messages to a chatBox, the chatBox will show it from the new top so you have to have it so it doesn't automatically scroll all the way up.

Comment: Oh. Well... those elements being prepended don't have some weird css applied before hand, do they? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100099/checking-for-scrollheight-of-an-element-sometimes-returning-0

Comment: As long as the css is there, `bodies[index].getBoundingClientRect().height;` should return anything other than 0 if there is height to the element.

Comment: No, the css is pretty standard stuff. And right, so the mystery is why height returns 0 when I can clearly see it and scroll on the element.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by replacing bodies[index] with item. Perhaps there was a bug that occurs when more than one variable is associated with an element.

Comment: Nice to know that bodies[index] and item are the same. Glad you figured it out tho :)